# NSTimer Syntax in Xcode 3

Tags: objective-c, xcode3.2

I'm using an old 12" Powerbook for the brains of a mobile robot platform and I'm having trouble getting the NSTimer to compile in XCode 3.2.3.  Creating a standard tool in C, Using:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
target:self
selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:NO];
```

When I build I get a "Syntax error before [ token." or "Syntax Error before { token." depending on where the NSTimer call shows up.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

> Creating a standard tool **in C** *[emphasis mine]*

This is Objective-C syntax, and `NSTimer` is an Objective-C object. The C compiler doesn't know what to do with it. You should start with the "Command Line Tool" Template, and specify "Foundation" in the pop-up menu. Foundation is Apple's base Objective-C framework. It includes `NSTimer` and also importantly, the build settings for your project will include compiling as Objective-C.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are linking against Foundation in your project, though I would expect missing symbol error in that case.

Your syntax for this line of code is correct, so it is not related directly to this line.